# Compare first letter string of previous value in row after foreach loop pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The code i am using, but doesnt give the proper result.

```
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
        $a = "$row[Description_code]";
        $aa = $a[0]; // first of string
        $b = prev($a);
        $bb = $b[0];  // first of string

echo "$aa";
if ($aa != $bb){
                 echo "<p></p>";
               }
                                     }
```

This isnt working like it should, results of $aa looks like AAABBCCCCDDEEFFFF etc
If A != A it should give page break, resulting in html
AAA

BB

CCCC

DD

EE

FFFF

Comment: your code makes no sense and stinks of cargo-cult programming. how could $aa and $bb **EVER** be different? they're both pulling the exact same data from the exact same string.

Comment: b is the previous value so why can this not be different?

Comment: no, it's not. strings are NOT arrays. the fact that you can access individual characters using array notation doesn't make them arrays. $anystring[0] is ALWAYS going to be the FIRST character of that string, no matter how many times you run it through prev/end/whatever.

Comment: that is obvious, but $b is  previous of $a = "$row[Description_code] not the string

Comment: $a[0] is not going to change just because you ran prev($a). so $b will be the exact same as $a, and therefore $bb the exact same as $a.

Comment: ok, maybe you can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're unable to understand what I'm saying, an example:

```
php > $a = 'abcdefghijkl';
php > $aa = $a[0];
php > $b = prev($a);
PHP Warning:  prev() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in php shell code on line 1
php > $bb = $b[0];
php > echo "$a $aa $b $bb\n";
abcdefghijkl a
 ^^-- $a     ^--$aa    hey! where's $b & $bb ?????
```

As the warning above says, you **CANNOT** use `prev()` on a string, because it's **NOT** an array.

Your code should be:

```
$previous_char = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $string = $row['Description of Code'];
    $first_char = substr($string, 0, 1);
    if ($first_char <> $previous_char) {
       echo '<p></p>';
       $previous_char = $first_char;
    }
    echo $first_char;
}
```

Your code, even if it written properly, could **NEVER** work, because you never consider the data from the PREVIOUS row of data fetched. You only consider the data from the CURRENT row. The first char of the current row will always match itself, so you never get a line break.

Comment: wow i have so much to learn, thank you will look in to it deeply.